# Computed value returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

My idea is to render certain buttons inside navigation for certain user role. I have array of this buttons, and each of them has field: `permission` that is telling what type of permission user have to have to see this button. Then my computed value filters the array returning the buttons that permission is fulfilled with permission of logged in user that I store in vuex.

PROBLEM: When I login and the computed value should return only matching buttons it returns me empty array.

This is my array with buttons:

```
  public items = [
    { text: 'Strona główna', icon: 'mdi-home', path: '/', permission: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { text: 'Znajdź Mecz', icon: 'mdi-map-search', path: '/findGame', permission: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { text: 'Niższe Ligi', icon: 'mdi-soccer', path: '/leagues', permission: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    { text: 'Dodaj Artykuł', icon: 'mdi-file-document-plus', path: '/addArticle', permission: [1] },
  ];
```

As you can see each role has array of permission of which users can see this button.
I am rendering this buttons in a v-for loop:

```
<v-list-item class="my-3" v-for="(item, i) in navBarOptions" :key="i" :to="item.path">
    <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon large v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
    </v-list-item-icon>
    <v-list-item-content class="py-3">
        <v-list-item-title class="py-1 text-h6 font-weight-bold" v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

And here is computed value (`navBarOptions`):

```
  get navBarOptions() {
    const userRole = user.userData?.role.id_role;
    if (userRole != null) {
console.log("Im here" + userRole);
      return this.items.filter((i) => i.permission.includes(userRole));
    } else {
      return this.items.filter((i) => i.permission.includes(4));
    }
  }
```

When application starts, user is not logged in, so the `naavBarOptions` return buttons with permission 4 (unLogged User). Then if I login as admin, I can see in this `conole.log` that my role changed to 1. But in this moment even though this filter looks properly I get empty array.

PS Debuggin:
I add small console.log debugging:

```
if (userRole != null) {
      return (this.items = this.items.filter((i) => {
        i.permission.includes(userRole);
        console.log(i.permission);
        console.log(userRole);
        console.log(i.permission.includes(userRole));
      }));
    } else {
```

[DEBUG CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzPaF.png)

Comment: hard to tell here what `user` is